# Iphone Sharekit Error Code 100

Tags: iphone, facebook, share, sharekit

I have some problems with Sharekit.I am getting this error:

> An error occured with app_name .Please try again later.
>   API Error Code: 100
>   API Error Description: Invalid parameter
>   Error Message: Requires valid redirect URI .

I don't know why this happens.Please help.Thanks.

Comment: ShareKit API . I don't know any other API

Comment: It's happening because you don't have a valid redirect URI just as the error says: **Requires valid redirect URI**

Answer (score 2):

Based on Rutger's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721333/facebook-android-sdk-throwing-missing-redirect-uri-on-authetication).

Go to your Facebook App Developer Page, Settings > Advanced and disable the "Enhanced Auth Dialog".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's just that you (and I) downloaded the files from the ShareKit website. They are out of date, and if you download them from the Git repository at https://github.com/ideashower/sharekit/ the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error "An error occured with app_name. Please try again later" when using facebook sharekit. Defining valid SHKMyAppURL in SHKConfig.h solved the problem for me.