# Authentication using Facebook iOS SDK with Safari throws API Error code: 100

Tags: ios, facebook

Testing my app on the Simulator requires Facebook authentication.
Since Facebook app is not installed on the simulator, Facebook uses Safari for authentication.
Apparently something changed in Facebook Authentication flow, **which causes to users who already authenticated my app in the past to be redirected to an error page saying:**

> API Error Code: 100
>   API Error Description: Invalid parameter
>   Error Message: Requires valid redirect URI.

Everything worked fine before.

**Temporary Solution**:
Apparently it happens in Android as well, it has to do with the new Facebook authentication dialog.

As explained here: [Facebook Android sdk throwing missing redirect uri on Authetication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721333/facebook-android-sdk-throwing-missing-redirect-uri-on-authetication/7756183#7756183)

Go to your Facebook app settings page --> Advanced page --> Migrations --> Disable "Enhanced Auth Dialog"

Comment: The issue was reported on Facebook bugs: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/202310766508770

Answer (score 0):

Use the Facebook API. Ray Wenderlich has a good tutorial