# Facebook Android sdk throwing missing redirect uri on Authentification

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, single-sign-on

I have the same issue than in this link : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721333/facebook-android-sdk-throwing-missing-redirect-uri-on-authetication)

But disabling the Enhanced Auth Dialog in the Advanced Settings of my app don't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue in my Android application.
Disabling Enhanced Auth Dialog changes the error to the more general "error occurred" message so it doesn't fix the problem at all.
As a second test I removed permissions for the popular FriendCaster android application from my account and tried a fresh login. It has the exact same error.

So it seems like a temporary Facebook bug and hopefully they will fix it soon.

As a reference: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/381202678591889

Comment: seem's to be true, that work's now without modification from me (0o')